# JPA: ignore field on save, but fetch on select

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am using Hibernate as my JPA provider, and I want one of the fields in an entity to be ignored when calling `save()`. However, I do have a matching column in the corresponding database table and I want my entity field to be populated with the database value when I fetch the entity. So, I want the field to be ignored when saving the entity, but not when fetching it.

If I use `@Transient`, the field is completely ignored, which is not what I want. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

From the excellent book *[Pro JPA 2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430249269)* :

> JPA defines options to set individual mappings to be read-only using
>   the insertable and updatable elements of the @Column and @JoinColumn
>   annotations. These two settings default to true but can be set to
>   false if we want to ensure that the provider will not insert or update
>   information in the table in response to changes in the entity
>   instance. If the data in the mapped table already exists and we want
>   to ensure that it will not be modified at runtime, then the
>   insertable and updatable elements can be set to false, effectively
>   preventing the provider from doing anything other than reading the
>   entity from the database.

```
@Column(insertable = false, updatable = false)
private String readOnlyField;
```

Comment: That help me, but how to get the value, if for example, this value is generated by default into my database?

Comment: In this case, the field is ignored and the value generated by database is not returned and stay to null

Comment: I have the same problem described by you. I have a field that is automatically generated by the database(default value) and it is not being returned by the save method, it just returns null. I have tried calling .flush() after saving but that did not work either. Did you get to the bottom of this?

Comment: UPDATE: In my case, I have a column `modified_at` and default value is current datetime. The only thing that worked for me was [@UpdateTimestamp](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/UpdateTimestamp.html). I did not need to call `.flush()`.

Neither [@Generated](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/Generated.html) or [@GeneratedValue](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/GeneratedValue.html) annotations worked, even after using `.flush()` the field would still come back as null after a `.save()`.

Comment: Thank you, it helped. But also I had a `java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'someobject0_.somereadonlyfield' in 'field list'` when I tried to delete `someobject` by default `JpaRepository` method: `someObjectsRepository.deleteById(someObjectId)`. Custom delete query helped me: `@Query("delete from someobject where id = :someObjectId", nativeQuery = true)`